# ionic 2 local notifications not working when app close

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, localnotification

I am using ionic 2 local notification. Local notification not working when I remove the app from background.

This is sample code

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
        text: 'Delayed ILocalNotification',
        every:'minute',
        at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60000),
        led: 'FF0000',
        sound: null
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this push notification. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/

the local notification requires the app running in background.